# Spring MVC Mock Error

Tags: testing, model-view-controller, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I want to use spring mvc test for unit testing, but occur the following error, anyone help?

> Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition.setTargetType(Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;)V
>
> ```
>   at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.createBeanDefinition(MockitoPostProcessor.java:208)
>   at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.registerMock(MockitoPostProcessor.java:187)
>   at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.register(MockitoPostProcessor.java:178)
>   at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(MockitoPostProcessor.java:148)
>   at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(MockitoPostProcessor.java:135)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
>   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>
>
> Process finished with exit code 255
> ```

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebAPIController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class WebAPIControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean(classes = NotifyTaskService.class)
    private NotifyTaskService notifyTaskService;

    @Autowired
    private WebAPIController webAPIController;

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
    }

    /**
     * Method: sendNotifyAPI(String systemKey, String user, String type, String mechanism, String defaultMethod, String msgContent)
     */
    @Test
    public void testSendNotifyAPI() throws Exception {

    }
```

Comment: `Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` sounds like dependency problem, post your dependencies maybe.

Comment: i have checked the pom.xml, still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

another question, how to inject the mock object to the bean.

```
public class WebAPIController {
        @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Autowired
    private NotifyTaskService notifyTaskService;
  .......
}

public class WebAPIControllerTest {
     @Mock
    private NotifyTaskService notifyTaskService;

     @Autowired
    private WebAPIController webAPIController;
..........
}
```

how to inject 'notifyTaskService' to 'webAPIController'?

Comment: you should not ask question in answer :). you need to use @MockBean annotation.. Spring will automatically inject the mocked bean. you did this in your original question.. not sure what is the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring-boot-starter-test go through the following guide:
[Testing Web Layer with Spring Boot Test](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

I prefer the last example that uses `@WebMvcTest`, here you can mock your NotifyTaskService using `@MockBean`.